# ANCOVA on measurements with errors

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, ancova

I have measurements of a variable Y as a function of time, from two different categories (young & old).

This gives me a regression line for each category and I am interested in testing whether the gradients of the two lines are significantly different at the 5% confidence level.

The problem is that each Y measurement has an error associated with it, and I can't find any guidance online as to how to adapt ANCOVA to deal with measurements with error.

Example:

gradient(young) = 5.0 +/- 1.0

gradient(old) = 3.5 +/- 0.5

Are the two gradients significantly different?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify your ANCOVA if only Y is a "noisy" variable (i.e., one with measurement error), since the estimated model coefficients obtained via Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) for your ANCOVA model with a "noisy" dependent variable are unbiased. However, these coefficients will be estimated less precisely when Y is "noisy" (i.e., they will have larger standard errors than if Y had no "noise"). See, for example, these nice course notes: https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/dranove/htm/dranove/coursepages/Mgmt%20469/noisy-variables.pdf.

There is the complicating factor that your Y measurements are collected over time and may be temporally correlated.